# Cassandra: How to model data so that percentage change in time ranges can be calculated?

Tags: cassandra

I have very huge amount of data, which I plan to store in Cassandra. I am new to Cassandra and am trying to find a data model that will work for me.

My data is various parameters for commodities gathered over irregular time intervals:

```
commodity_id | timestamp    | param1 | param2 
c1           | '2018-01-01' | 5      | 15
c1           | '2018-01-03' | 7      | 15
c1           | '2018-01-08' | 8      | 10
c2           | '2018-01-01' | 100    | 13
c2           | '2018-01-02' | 140    | 13
c2           | '2018-01-05' | 130    | 13
c2           | '2018-01-06' | 150    | 13
```

I need to query the database, and get commodity IDs by "percentage change" in the params.

Ex. Find out all commodities whose param2 increased by more than 50% between '2018-01-02' and '2018-01-06'

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE "commodity" (
    commodity_id text,
    timestamp date,
    param1 int,
    param2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (commodity_id, timestamp)
)
```

You should be fine with this table. You can expect daysPerYear entries for a commodity partition, which is reasonably small so you dont need any artificial keys. Even if you have a large number of commodities, you wont run out of partitions, as the murmur3 partitioner actually has a range of -2^63 to +2^63-1. That are 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible values.

I would pull the data from cassandra and calculate the values in the app layer.

Comment: Can you please also mention how you will be pulling the data?

Comment: select * from commodity where commodity_id = "c1" and timestamp > xxx